# Sidekiq ActiveJob track spawned jobs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

A lot of time I will have background worker code that looks like this.

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base

 def perform
   User.find_in_batches.each do |batch|
     MyOtherJobToProcessBatchOfUsers.perform_later(batch)
   end
 end
end
```

Basically, one jobs that spawns many child jobs. Is there an easy way to know when all of the jobs are finished? I know I could increment a counter in the parent job and have each child job decrement that counter. But as anyone who has tried to do that will tell you, you can run into some complications.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Sidekiq Pro's Batch feature does.  You are right: it's incredibly difficult to build correctly.  I don't know of any open source library that implements it.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches
http://sidekiq.org/pro/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. I am a huge sidekiq fan! I was thinking that since when you enqueue a job it returns a jid that is also in redis, would it be possible to collect all those jids and check redis to see if they are still running? This might require keeping one job warm to do some sort of redis polling though.

Comment: Whelp, after reading your wiki, it looks like I sort of described how batches work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anything is possible, only you know your requirements, budget and schedule.  The tough part is building something that works 100% of the time, handles job errors, doesn't poll Redis, etc.